# How to overlay a netcdf4 raster image on world map?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, netcdf, netcdf4

I am attempting to plot a world map of aerosol height data pulled from the Sentinel 5 Precursor/TROPOMI level 2 data from the data hub available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z15ag7f4uq090l8/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc?dl=0) on dropbox.

I am specifically looking at Hawaii (5-30 degree N, 130-180 degree W) and am attempting to plot the aerosol height which is in netcdf4 (.nc) format.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(ggmap)
library(rworldmap)
library(maps)
library(usmap)
library(sf)
library(rasterVis)
library(lattice)

ncname <- "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc"
nc <- nc_open(ncname)

lon <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/longitude")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/latitude")
time <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/time_utc")
ah <- ncvar_get(nc, varid = "PRODUCT/aerosol_mid_height")

test <- raster("S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc", 
               varname = "PRODUCT/aerosol_mid_height", 
               xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), 
               crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs=0,0,0"))

plot(test)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = TRUE)
```

Resulting image [distorted image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDl0P.png)

```
> wrld_simpl
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 246 
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 83.57027  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         :  +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 11
names       : FIPS, ISO2, ISO3,  UN,           NAME,    AREA,    POP2005, REGION, SUBREGION,      LON,     LAT 
min values  :     ,   AD,  ABW,   4, Aaland Islands,       0,          0,      0,         0, -178.131, -80.446 
max values  :   ZI,   ZW,  ZWE, 894,       Zimbabwe, 1638094, 1312978855,    150,       155,  179.219,   78.83 

> test
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3245, 448, 1453760  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
**extent     : -0.5, 447.5, -0.5, 3244.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)**
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : /Users/mattcohen/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc 
names      : Height.at.center.of.aerosol.layer.relative.to.geoid 
z-value    : 269308800 
zvar       : PRODUCT/aerosol_mid_height
```

Additionally, when I try:

```
r <- brick(ncname, var = "PRODUCT/aerosol_mid_height")
plot(r)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = TRUE)
```

The resulting image is still distorted
[distorted image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Faldr.png)

```
show(r)
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 3245, 448, 1453760, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -0.5, 447.5, -0.5, 3244.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : /Users/mattcohen/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc 
names      : X269308800 
PRODUCT/time (seconds since 2010-01-01 00:00:00): 269308800 
varname    : PRODUCT/aerosol_mid_height
```

I believe there is a disconnect between the projections of `wrld_simpl` and `test`. The **extent** class for `test` also seems peculiar. Does anyone know why this problem is occurring? Thank you in advance.

Update

```
s1 <- data.frame(as.vector(lon), as.vector(lat), as.vector(ah))
crsLatLon <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
ex <- extent(c(-180,180,-90,90))
pmraster <- raster(ncol=360*10, nrow=180*10, crs=crsLatLon,ext=ex)
pmraster <- rasterize(s1[,1:2], pmraster, s1[,3], fun=mean, na.rm=T)

exHI <- extent(c(-180,-140,10,30))
levelplot(crop(pmraster,exHI))
```

When attempting to plot, I receive this error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Why am I unable to plot the raster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to read from a ncdf file with raster is:

```
library(raster)
ncname <- "~/Desktop/Summer 2020/Tropomi/Aerosol Height/S5P_RPRO_L2__AER_LH_20180715T201241_20180715T215609_03908_01_010301_20190530T173144.nc"
r <- brick(ncname, var = "PRODUCT/aerosol_mid_height")

plot(r)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = TRUE)
```

If that does not look good, what does `show(r)` show?  And please make a small example file available.

Looking at the file I see that it is does not follow that CF standard that raster (or terra/GDAL) expects. And it may need transformation of some sort. The coordinates are in (PRODUCT/ground_pixel, PRODUCT/scanline). That is, they refer to pixels, not to coordinates, and I cannot see where they are, of they are evenly spaced etc. The file also says that the lat/lon bounds are global. One could hope for the best and do the below but I would not trust this without verification.

```
 extent(r) <- c(-180,180,-90,90)
```

To see all the metadata you can do

```
 print(r)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Robert. I tried your approach but the new image is still distorted (the countries shifted right slightly). I have modified my question to read more clearly, included your suggestion in the question and there is now a reproducible file included as a link at the start of my question.

Comment: The file you provided appears corrupted. Can you fix it?

Comment: Sorry! I have now posted it to dropbox. I believe it should be able to be downloaded now.